# macro generate code depending on int template value

Tags: c++, macros

I'm still learning c++, and writing a particle simulation lib for it.
I want to optimize my working code as much as possible, and my next bottleneck are my vector operators.

I created a template vector class that depends on the type contained in the vector and the dimension :

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
class Vector {
    private:
    T values[D];
}
```

My operators are then defined like so :

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
Vector<T, D> operator+(const Vector<T, D>& v1, const Vector<T, D>& v2) {
    T values [D];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < D; i++) {
        values[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
    return Vector<T, D>(values);
}
```

In my simulation, I end up doing lot of vector computations, and I would like to try to optimize this.

My first assumption is that I could get rid of the loop and have something like this if I knew the dimension in advance :

```cpp
T values[3];
values[0] = v1[0] + v2[0];
values[1] = v1[1] + v2[1];
values[2] = v1[2] + v2[2];
return Vector<T, 3>(values);
```

So I've though of a recursive macro that would look like this :

```cpp
#define vec_sum(D, values, v1, v2) if D > 0 {
    vec_sum(D-1, values, v1, v2)
    values[D-1] = v1[D-1] + v2[D-1];
} else {
    values[0] = v1[0] + v2[0];
}
```

and then, my function would look like :

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
Vector<T, D> operator+(const Vector<T, D>& v1, const Vector<T, D>& v2) {
    T values [D];
    vec_sum(D, values, v1, v2)
    return Vector<T, D>(values);
}
```

Are such code generation possible with c++ ?

Comment: Note even if you want to do this, don't use macros. You can write a recursive template function too (possibly using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often you won't gain a benefit, if you enable compiler optimization.

If you want to do this though, you can do so without using macros by using a helper function, [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and a fold expression (requires C++17):

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
class Vector {
private:
    T values[D];

    template<size_t ... Is>
    static constexpr Vector PlusImpl(Vector const& s1, Vector const& s2, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        Vector result;
        ((result.values[Is] = s1.values[Is] + s2.values[Is]), ...);
        return result;
    }

    friend constexpr Vector operator+(Vector const& s1, Vector const& s2)
    {
        return PlusImpl(s1, s2, std::make_index_sequence<D>());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

That's pointless to do by hand. Compilers can do the loop unrolling themselves as an optimization step.

If you notice, after reading the generated assembly and benchmarking properly, that the compiler does not optimize ideally, you can add compiler-specific attributes to the loop to inform the compiler to unroll it.

Whether or not unrolling is beneficial is also non-obvious and depends on the exact circumstances. If you didn't benchmark and don't have deeper knowledge of the architecture/CPU you are compiling for, then don't assume by default that it must be more performant.

Comment: Fun video [What has my compiler done for me lately (Matt Godbolt)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4). And assume your compiler knows better how to unrol, what branche prediction and cache prefetching to do then you do. Also compilers can generate vectorized assembly for you too. Have you ever tried : [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/)? This shows you generated assembly for various compilers and their optimization options.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use constexpr techniques, and make `vec_sum` macro a constexpr function.

The first problem with your preprocessor macro, is that it unfolds before your template is instantiated.
Second is, macros don’t work recursively.
Meaning, `vec_sum(D-1, values, v1, v2)` won’t work, and your compiler will most likely complain that you call an undefined Function `vec_sum(D-1, values, v1, v2)`, or complain about missing tokens.